# Pasting 100k rows into Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

So copying and pasting obviously isn't the way to do this...

What is the way? I can't seem to find clear answers anywhere, and sorry if this has already been asked.
My use case is copying form Excel but I can imagine there are other cases.

Best to do this in batches maybe?

EDIT: The first thing I tried was, of course, uploading the Excel straight to drive. But Drive won't open the file.
[image]

Comment: Uplaod it to the drive and then open with spreadsheetApp? File -> Save as Google sheet?

Comment: Google sheets can have maximum 5 million cells only. So check if your data crosses that limit than you can not paste it in google sheets.

Comment: I tried the first option Remco. It won't open! It only has 150k rows :/

Comment: How long are your rows? Is the [answer suggested by Tom Sharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64361318) working for you?

Comment: nope. my rows aren't that long, really... say 20 columns.
Overall its a 20MB excel file - no reason why it shouldn't be opening, really.

I guess what I'm also asking for here is the best practice way to get huge swathes of data into google sheets. Using the API, maybe?

Comment: 150k rows per 20 columns adds up to 3 million cells, just in one sheet. You're getting uncomfortably close to the limit of 5 million cells with just one sheet. I think that's the reason for your issue. Would splitting your Excel into several files be an appropriate workaround for your situation? Of course, you could use Sheets API to copy your data, but you will probably get to the same limit when doing that, if you don't want to split this into different files.